# jqgrid - resize and overlay

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Jquery Grid</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/ui.multiselect.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style>
            .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
                overflow: inherit !important;
            }
            .overlay{
                position: absolute;
                border: 1px solid black;
                background-color: black;
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <table id="myjqgrid"></table>
         <div id="Pager"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "colModel": [
        {
            "name": "Overlay",
            "label": "Overlay",
            "width": 60,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.0.value",
            "sortable": true      
        },
        {
            "name": "ID",
            "label": "ID",
            "width": 60,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.1.value",
            "sortable": true      
        },
        {
            "name": "FirstName",
            "label": "FirstName",
            "width": 100,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.2.value",
            "sortable": false       
        },
        {
            "name": "LastName",
            "label": "LastName",
            "width": 100,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.3.value",
            "sortable": false       
        }
    ],
    "colNames": [
        "Overlay",
        "ID",
        "FirstName",
        "LastName"
    ],
    "mypage": {
        "outerwrapper": {
            "page":"1",
            "total":"1",
            "records":"20",
            "innerwrapper": {
                "rows":[
                    {
                        "id":"1",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"12345",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"David",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Smith",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"2",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"37546",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Willy",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Peacock",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"3",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"62345",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Kim",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Holmes",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"4",
                        "cells":
                        [  
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },             
                            {
                                "value":"186034",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Andy",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Wills",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"5",
                        "cells":
                        [
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },               
                            {
                                "value":"67345",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Paul",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Lawrence",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"6",
                        "cells":
                        [
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },               
                            {
                                "value":"12906",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Andy",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Charlery",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"7",
                        "cells":
                        [ 
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },              
                            {
                                "value":"564565",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Bets",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Josilyn",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"8",
                        "cells":
                        [
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },               
                            {
                                "value":"34345",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Pink",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Floyd",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"9",
                        "cells":
                        [ 
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },              
                            {
                                "value":"3429",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Rose",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Ben",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"10",
                        "cells":
                        [
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },               
                            {
                                "value":"6668",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Amy",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Wills",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"11",
                        "cells":
                        [
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },               
                            {
                                "value":"22786",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Zarine",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Khan",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"12",
                        "cells":
                        [
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },               
                            {
                                "value":"56444",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Dolly",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Mathews",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"13",
                        "cells":
                        [ 
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },              
                            {
                                "value":"99453",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Ginger",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Wills",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"14",
                        "cells":
                        [
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },               
                            {
                                "value":"1234",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Fabrice",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Papa",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"15",
                        "cells":
                        [
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },               
                            {
                                "value":"45000",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Helen",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Kites",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"16",
                        "cells":
                        [
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },               
                            {
                                "value":"1255",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Barbara",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Dorris",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"17",
                        "cells":
                        [
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },               
                            {
                                "value":"5555",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Eugene",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Mark",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"18",
                        "cells":
                        [ 
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },              
                            {
                                "value":"1867",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Harry",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"King",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"19",
                        "cells":
                        [ 
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },              
                            {
                                "value":"45888",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Lorraine",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Williams",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"20",
                        "cells":
                        [ 
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },              
                            {
                                "value":"4567777",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Mark",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Sheppard",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"21",
                        "cells":
                        [ 
                            {
                                "value":"Click Me!",
                                "label": "Overlay"                       
                            },              
                            {
                                "value":"7777",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Davis",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Sheppard",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JQGrid Definition**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myjqgrid.json",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            var columnData = response.mypage.outerwrapper,
                columnNames = response.colNames,
                columnModel = response.colModel;

            $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                datastr: columnData,                
                colNames: columnNames,
                colModel: columnModel,
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "innerwrapper.rows",              
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                gridview: true,
                pager: "#Pager",
                rowNum: 21,
                rowList: [21],
                viewrecords: true,              
                recordpos: 'left',
                multiboxonly: true,
                multiselect: true,
                sortname: 'ID',
                sortorder: "desc",  
                sorttype: "text",   
                sortable: true,
                caption: "<h2>MY JQGRID</h2>",
                width: "1406",      
                height: "100%",
                scrolloffset: 0,    
                loadonce: true,     
                cache: true,
                loadComplete: function(){
                    $("td[title = 'Click Me!']").live("click", function(){
                        $("div.overlay").remove();
                        var RowID = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
                        if ($(this).siblings("div").length == 0) {
                            $(this).closest("td").append("<div class='overlay' id='"+RowID+"'>This is an overlay.</div>");
                            $(this).siblings("div#" + RowID).css("display", "block");
                        }   
                    })
                }
            });
            $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#Pager', {add:false, edit:false, del:false, position: 'right'});
            $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('gridResize',{minWidth:800,maxWidth:1405,minHeight:350,maxHeight:680});               
        }
    });
});
```

**PROBLEM THAT I AM HAVING**

- the pagination works fine when I resize the grid **if I don't change the CSS**
- **if I change the CSS FROM** `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {overflow: auto;}` **TO**   `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {overflow: inherit !important;}`, *the pagination bar flows between the records*
- **the reason I am changing the CSS is because** I have an overlay that is displayed when I click on "Click Me!" link in the second column of every row. Changing the CSS displays the overlay correctly for the last record on the page. If I don't change the CSS, the overlay for the last record on the page is hidden.

Thus,

**I do not change the CSS**

- pagination works fine when I resize the grid
- the overlay for the last record on the page is hidden

**I change the CSS**

- pagination bar is displayed between the records when I resize the grid
- the overlay for the last records on the page is displayed correctly

*I tried using CSS positioning and z-index for the overlay but it didn't work.*

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the sense of the overlay which you placed in the `<td>` cell with the title `'Click Me!'`. The usage of `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {overflow: inherit !important;}` is definitively the wrong way. Moreover probably you should use `ui-widget-overlay` class to be compatible with the jQuery UI CSS which you use. In any way to be able to help you I should first understand what you try to achieve.

Comment: The overlay is specific to every row, therefore the overlay is placed in the `<td>` cell. To trigger the overlay, I have the text "Click Me!" in the cell. This can be an image as well instead of text. I've posted all the code. I don't know how to create a demo link for you. The overlay works fine except in the last row of the page where it is hidden below the pagination bar.

Comment: Do you want display a div with some information if the user click on the cell from the "Overlay" column? The div should stay visible if the user select any other row of the grid? Is your problem just to display the div over close to the clicked point, but over the whole grid inclusive the pager? If the size of the div will be large should be also over the other elements on the page?

Comment: **Do you want display a div with some information if the user click on the cell from the "Overlay" column?** - Yes, I want to display some information if the user clicks on the text "Click Me!". **The div should stay visible if the user select any other row of the grid?** - No. If the user selects any other row of the grid, then the overlay for that particular row should open up. **Is your problem just to display the div over close to the clicked point, but over the whole grid inclusive the pager?** - Yes, the div should display over close to the clicked point. NOT over the whole grid.

Comment: **If the size of the div will be large should be also over the other elements on the page?** - Yes

Comment: Can you please copy over my code to see what's happening? Or you can tell me how to create a demo link for you. **I repeat** - The overlay is working fine. It is just **hiding under the pagination bar when you click on "Click Me!" in the last row of the grid page**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need do something like the following

```
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
    $("#myoverlay").remove();
    if (this.p.colModel[iCol].name === 'Overlay') { // iCol === 1
        $('<div class="overlay" id="myoverlay">This is an overlay.</div>').css({
            top: e.pageY,
            left: e.pageX
        }).appendTo('body');
    }
}
```

instead of the code in the `loadComplete`. Important is that the code above append the div to `<body>` instead of `<td>` element. One can just use the `event` of the click to place the div in the corresponding position.

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-7.htm).

You can easy modify the code to use the content of the div depend on the `rowid`, `cellcontent` or any other criteria.

By the way. In the HTML code which you use you should use `<!DOCTYPE html ...` before `<html>` and use `type="text/css"` attribute in the `<style>`. jqGrid has no `cache: true` option.

Comment: @SK11: What is the problem with the question?

Comment: @SK11: Sorry, but writing of answers on the stackoverflow is not my job. I don't forgot your questions. I'll look the questions later when I'll have free time for it.

Comment: Oleg, can you pls help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021773/jqgrid-display-an-overlay-when-in-inline-editing-mode