# jqgrid - display an overlay when in inline editing mode

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

The column `FirstName` is editable. When the grid loads, I'm adding a `div` as a child of the `FirstName <td>` in every row.

**What I want to do**

In inline editing mode, **if I enter anything in the textfield of `FirstName` column** - the `div` overlay should appear right below the textfield.

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Jquery Grid</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/ui.multiselect.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <table id="myjqgrid"></table>
         <div id="pager"></div>
         <script src="js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                  
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "colModel": [
        {
            "name": "ID",
            "label": "ID",
            "width": 60,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.0.value",
            "sortable": true,
            "editable": false      
        },
        {
            "name": "FirstName",
            "label": "FirstName",
            "width": 100,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.1.value",
            "sortable": false,
            "editable": true,
            "edittype": "text"       
        },
        {
            "name": "LastName",
            "label": "LastName",
            "width": 100,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.2.value",
            "sortable": false,
            "editable": false      
        }
    ],
    "colNames": [
        "ID",
        "FirstName",
        "LastName"
    ],
    "mypage": {
        "outerwrapper": {
            "page":"1",
            "total":"1",
            "records":"20",
            "innerwrapper": {
                "rows":[
                    {
                        "id":"1",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"12345",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"David",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Smith",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"2",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"37546",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Willy",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Peacock",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"3",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"62345",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Kim",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Holmes",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    }                   
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JQGrid**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var serverData = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.json",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            var columnData = response.mypage.outerwrapper,
                columnNames = response.colNames,
                columnModel = response.colModel;

            $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                datastr: columnData,                
                colNames: columnNames,
                colModel: columnModel,
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "innerwrapper.rows",                              
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                gridview: true,
                pager: "#pager",
                rowNum: 15,
                rowList: [15, 30, 45, 60],
                viewrecords: true,              
                recordpos: 'left',
                multiboxonly: true,
                multiselect: true,
                sortname: 'ID',
                sortorder: "desc",  
                sorttype: "text",   
                sortable: true,
                width: "1406",
                height: "auto",     
                scrolloffset: 0,    
                loadonce: true,     
                caption: "My JQGrid",               
                onSelectRow: function(id){                  
                    $("table#myjqgrid").editRow(id, true);                                      
                    $("input.editable").live("keyup", function(e){
                        $("div#overlay").show();
                    });
                },
                loadComplete: function(){
                    var x, y, cellProperty, itemRows;
                    for (x = 0; x < response.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows.length; x++) {
                        itemRows = response.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows[x];
                        itemRowsID = response.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows[x].id;
                        serverData[itemRows.id] = itemRows.cells;
                        var cellCount = response.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows[x].cells.length;
                        for (y = 0; y < cellCount; y += 1) {
                            cellProperty = response.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows[x].cells[y];
                            var cellLabel = cellProperty.label;
                            if (cellLabel === "FirstName") {                                
                                $("tr#" + itemRowsID + "td[aria-describedby='myjqgrid_" + cellLabel + "']").append("<div style='display:none;position:absolute;z-index:1000' id='overlay'>"+cellProperty.value+"</div>");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: You place currently the same text in the 'FirstName' column and in the overlay div. Do you really want to have as so or the div content can has another text later?

Comment: the div can have any text. Right now, the div is pushing the row down. I want the div to be an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code have some problems:

- You create "overlay" divs in every row of the grid, but all the dives receive **the same id**: "overlay". HTML don't permit use id duplicates on one page.
- You place the hidden div **inside** on the editable cell. The method `editRow` **overwite** the full content of the cell with `<input>` element. So the overlay div will be removed and can't be shown after the call of `editRow`. So you have to either move the overlay div to somewhere outside of the cell or save the text from the overlay's content somewhere else and create it dynamically somewhere near to editing of the row.

To place the overlay under the `<input>` element I recommend you to use [jQuery UI Position](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position).